# Connections and curvature in commutative algebra

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, connections

Since on any commutative algebra $R$ over ring $S$ we have module of Kahler differentials $(\Omega_{R/S},d)$ which extends to the algebraic de-Rham complex $(\Omega^\bullet,d),$ it is natural to define connection on $R$-module $P$ as any $S$-linear map $\nabla:P\to\Omega_{R/S}\otimes P$  such that
$$\nabla(rp)=dr\otimes p + r\nabla(p).$$
As in geometry we can extend $\nabla$ to $d^\nabla:\Omega^\bullet\otimes P\to\Omega^{\bullet+1}\otimes P$ and define its curvature $F^\nabla.$

I look for some source which analyze such approach. The only thing I found are [Sardanashvilys Lectures on Differential Geometry of Modules and Rings](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.1515) which define connection via jet bundle, but I guess it is equivalent definition. However this source is from 2009 and in 1995 [Dubois-Violette and Michor wrote Connections on central bimodules](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9503020) in which they investigate connections in noncommutative case. They also refer to Koszules Lectures on fibre bundles and differentials, but Koszul does not write anything about kahler differentials.

> **Question.** Is there any source which analyze connections from purely commutative algebraic point of view?
>
> Or maybe there is no point for such approach because there is no interesting connections beyond algebra of smooth functions on smooth manifold?

---

**Some footnote.**
In commutative algebra connections can be defined even for any dga as in [ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connection+for+a+differential+graded+algebra), but there is no reference so again I do not know where such case is investigated.

Comment: This is probably **not** what you are looking for, but there is Bertram's monograph "Differential Geometry over General Base Fields and Rings" (2005) and Betram, Glöckner and Neeb's "Differential Calculus, Manifolds, and Lie Groups over Arbitrary Infinite Fields" (2003). I don't know if their approach can be of any interest to you.

Comment: If your major concern is the rings of mappings, Peter Michor's works are mostly concerned with such manifolds corresponding to Lie-algebra/rings. But typically the focus is on Lie algebra, that is why the motivation comes from noncommutative cases. But nice question!

Comment: @July Thanks for the first one. I found something interesting in this book, but not related to the question. I looked through the book and I doubt I will find such construction there. Besides it is relatively new book. And I suspect the construction I wrote above should have been done in early 70s.

Comment: @Henry.L I am also interested in manifolds. I love Jet Nestruevs book and he (they) proved that $(\Omega^1(M),d)$ is a module of kahler differentials in the category of so called geometric modules. So any result from this abstract perspective would apply to manifold case.

Comment: There's plenty of approaches using infinitesimal neighborhoods of the diagonal. See for instance, Deligne's "Equations différentielles à points singuliers réguliers". Of course, books about algebraic analysis and D-modules also deal with this subject. There's the function field analogous of this too by using Frobenius (take a look at Goss book "Basic Structures of Function Field Arithmetic", there's some references there). From the point of view of arithmetic, there's also Buium's theory of arithmetic differential equations (see, for instance, http://www.math.unm.edu/~buium/adgintro.pdf).

Comment: By the way, in the link to the nlab, what's written is essentially the same thing as representations of $L_{\infty}$-algebroids . You can, of course, develop everything algebraically on schemes instead of dif. manifolds.

Comment: Perhaps you should check out the paper *Local Cohomological Dimension of Algebraic Varieties* by Arthur Ogus, (Annals of Mathematics
Second Series, Vol. 98, No. 2 (Sep., 1973), pp. 327-365). Not sure if that's what you are looking for but it may be relevant.

Comment: You may want to try and look in the characteristic classes chapter at the end of the book "Complex Topological K-theory" by Efton Park. In it he discusses an approach for computing chern classes using connections which has a distinctly algebraic flavor.